# Fill a Dataframe column with list of values if condition is not satisfied based on some other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this -

```
col_1   |   col_2
-------------------
"red"   |    21
-------------------
"blue"  |    31
-------------------
"red"   |    12
-------------------
"blue"  |    99
-------------------
"blue"  |    102
```

I also have a list of values like this `label = [1,3,2]`

I want to construct a third column `col_3` which should have "**Yes**" if the colour is "**red**" in `col_1`, else should have 1,3,2 on respective rows. Basically, should have values from the label one after the other if colour is "**blue**".

**Expected output** -

```
col_1   |   col_2    | col_3
---------------------------
"red"   |    21      |  "Yes"
-----------------------------
"blue"  |    31      |  "1"
------------------------------
"red"   |    12      | "Yes"
------------------------------
"blue"  |    99      |  "3"
------------------------------
"blue"  |    102     |  "2"
```

**My Approach** -

I have tried to impute using `np.where()` like this

```
np.where(df["col_1"]=="red","Yes",labels)
```

, but the

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
```

I believe this is due to the difference in the size of `df` and `labels` (5 vs 3).

Can anyone help me out, please?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

1. Expected Output added
2. Made some mistake in My Approach demonstration, corrected that.

Comment: Please post your exact expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Hi, Please check now.

Comment: @Ch3steR  This will never happen as the col_1 is always going to be a binary value "blue" or "red" and in the previous step I slice the blue values and make prediction on them, ignoring the "red". So, it would either be predicted value(labels) or "Yes".

Comment: That not what I meant. let's say you have 5 blues and 2 reds in `col1` and labels is `[1,3,2]`  what should be the output now?

Comment: @Ch3steR The scenario you are suggesting would never happen. Size of df will always be equal to labels + "Not interested". i.e "blues" will always be equals to labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with boolean masking. First, preemptively assign `Yes` to the whole column, then create a boolean mask using `Series.ne`. In your case create a mask where `col_1` values are not equal to `Red` and use that mask to populate values.

```
df['col_3'] = 'Yes'
m = df['col_1'].ne('Red') # ne -> not equal to
df.loc[m, 'col_3'] = label
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```py
df['col_3'] = 'Yes'
df.loc[(df['col_1'] != 'red'), 'col_3'] = label

print(df)
```

```
   col_1  col_2 col_3
0   red     21   Yes
1  blue     32     1
2   red     12   Yes
3  blue     99     3
4  blue    102     2
```

Comment: Thanks, let me quickly try this out.

Comment: This works great. However, I have no idea about the package "itertools". Will the performance of [next(seq) ...  shape[0] going to be good for large datasets too ?

Comment: I think the cyclic nature of col_3 makes it difficult. BTW itertools is efficient, the sequence generation can take some time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. +1. Accepted @ch3ster's answer just for simplicity :) Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems, I misunderstood your problem, you don't need Cycle. I assumed that you have only `[1,3,2]` and for 10 rows you need to do something like `[1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1]`. But your problem is much more simple. @MaxUU